# compose key not working after upgrade to Ubuntu MATE 17.04

Tags: 16.10, keyboard-layout, mate, 17.04, compose-key

EDIT 17apr2017: SAME PROBLEM AGAIN AFTER UPGRADING TO 17.04
EDIT 2 17apr2017: Fixed after installing ibus and anthy (for Japanese input), BUT: Shouldn't the compose key be able to work even without installing ibus/anthy?!?

ORIGINAL QUESTION(dec2016):
After upgrading from Ubuntu MATE 16.04 to 16.10 the compose key stopped working.
I checked my Keyboard settings (System-preferences-hardware-keyboard) 
Layout-Options-Compose key position and they appear ok. I had set left-win key
and it was still checked. I tried checking different keys, but none seem to work.
The machine is a 32bit netbook ; from a hardinfo report:
Processor   4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.53GHz
Memory  3929MB

Comment: What's the "keyboard input method system" setting in _Language Support_?

Comment: IBus (I also have Anthy for Japanese input)

Comment: Ok. there is [this subtle bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1573755), but it's mostly about XIM. One thing you can try is to launch a guest session from the login greeter, and check if the issue with the compose key is present there.

Comment: it does not work in the guest session either. Of course I had to set the compose key in the keybord layout options for the guest session too. I add that it does not work in any application that I tried: terminal, gvim, firefox, libreoffice...

Comment: It did work in 16.04 though. I add that I have a UK keyboard (real and layout) and the interface language is Italian.

Comment: maybe I should reinstall some software components in a different (appropriate?) order, but I don't know which ones - and I don't know the "appropriate order"!

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop`

Comment: YES, it works now, thank you Gunnar!  (not at once, though, I had to unset and then set again the compose key position in the keyboard layout settings- but it works now, thank you again)

Comment: Now it seems that upgrading to 17.04 recreates the same problem....old solution does not work, though (for the moment?)

Comment: I have no other idea for now. I'd suggest that you edit your question (e.g. change to 17.04) so others see that there is still a probem.